# Image gets blurry while retrieving with Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

So I am working on this chat app. I can send text messages as well as the images.

The problem is whenever I send the image or receive the image gets blurred. Although when I refresh the layout (I have SwipeRefreshLayout) images get clear.

I have the typical Adapter class, recyclerView and the layout for the images.

This is only Happening in Glide image library and works fine with Picasso. But I want to use Glide only. What could be the problem for this?

Here is how I am using Glide:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()){
        case 1:
            ViewHolder1 viewHolder1 = (ViewHolder1)holder;
            viewHolder1.Text.setText(messageList.get(position).getMessage());
            break;
         case 2:
            ViewHolder2 viewHolder2 = (ViewHolder2)holder;
            Glide.with(viewHolder2.Image.getContext())
                    .load(messageList.get(position).getMessage())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image_send_24dp)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(viewHolder2.Image);
            break;
    }
}
```

Below is the image layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/message_root"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_round_primary_color">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_message_image"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_image_send_24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I think that is an issue on your image loader library. Maybe you have to change settings or using another image loader library instead.

Comment: You are correct man. I was using glide earlier. When I changed it to Picasso it worked. Don't know why though.

Comment: Maybe your internet connection or image was too large and you load in without any compression. Happy coding!

Comment: I am compressing the images and they are way less than 100kb and internet connection is also not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I got the solution. In layout file in `Imageview` `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` should be something like `android:layout_height="250dp"`

**OR**

using `override(width, height)` in glide.